# How is a cubic root done in gnome-calculator?

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator

I don't know which buttons I have to click or what key combination to type to calculate a cube root.

Answer (score 20):

The n-th root is calculated when you put a subscript number before the square root sign.

```
₃√27
```

To enter subscript numbers with the keyboard hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while entering the number.

E.g.

1. Go to Advanced mode
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing <kbd>3</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>√</kbd>

and so on

Comment: Also you can open a bug report for add a button of n-th root.

Comment: X^(1/3) will do the same

Comment: @Helio That would be a feature request, not a bug report ;)

Comment: @CristianMirTienda Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).

Comment: I didn't know that!  :-)

Comment: The absolute best answer :) Also you would better to mention the `CTRL`+number for typing superscripts.

Answer (score 3):

Open Calculator and goto **Help>Contents** (or simply press <kbd>F1</kbd>), You will find help for **[Powers and Roots](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-calculator/3.14/power.html.en)**:-

[image]

Where you will find information that:

> n-th roots can be calculated by putting a **subscript number** before the root sign.
>   ₃√2

The superscripting and subscripting numbers can be put by holing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> respectively!.