# How to use non-square roots on the Default Calculator in advanced mode without exponents?

Tags: 18.04, calculator, gnome-calculator

I can't seem to figure out how to input a root that isn't square in Ubuntu's default calculator. I know I can input `4^(1 / 3)` but I'd prefer to input them in a more.. "natural" way.  (I can't think of a good way to put it.)

Is there a  way to work with non-square roots in the advanced mode of the calculator without using exponents?

Comment: Are you asking about cube roots and so on? if so see [How is a cubic root done in gnome-calculator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599098/how-is-a-cubic-root-done-in-gnome-calculator)